# How to capture the whole web page using QTP?

Tags: capture, qtp

How to capture the Whole web page when using QTP?
I am aware of 'CaptureBitmap' method for the screenshot. But how to capture the Whole page? Help !!

Comment: [try] [to] [refine] [your] [tags]

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to capture? If it's the HTML you can create a checkpoint on the `Page` test object and check the **HTML source** checkbox in the **HTML verification** section.

If you want to capture an image of the page then you can only capture the visible part with `CaptureBitmap` there is no way to get an image of the scrolled out parts (unless you scroll and use multiple captures).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Browser("").Capturebitmap`.

This takes the screenshot of the visible browser.
Use the sendkeys method to do a page down, then use `Browser("").Capturebitmap` again!

Answer (score 0):

A full screen shot can be taken by toggling QTP's run settings rather than using CaptureBitmap. We can tell QTP to always take screen shots, interact with the page (or object) we wish to capture (e.g. call .Exist(0)) and this will feed a screen shot in to the results.

The code to do this:

```
Dim App 'As Application
Set App = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
App.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "Always"
Browser("index:=0").Page("index:=0").sync
App.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnError"
```

Technically this seems to be capturing the html and then presenting this to the user in the run results, rather than an actual image of the browser's presentation of the html. But still, this means we can see what's on the page but not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have went through lot of surfing but couldn't get right answer or I coudn't implement what I found due to restriction of using third party APIs in my office. By using dot net factory, we can use dot net libraries to take screen shots and merge them. refer the below page for complete code

http://www.testbasket.com/2015/08/capture-whole-web-page-using-uftqtp.html

However here i have pasted the contents from the page and hope it helps.

In order to do take the screenshot of complete page, I have used DotNetFactory  and System.Drawing dot net library.

Lets go step by step to the solution,

As part of implementing the solution, we need to get the height and weight of the entire page. In order to get that we using DOM of a page using .object method.

```
#Get the Full Height of Page
FullHeight = Browser("Wikipedia, the free encycloped").Object.document.body.scrollheight

#Get the Full width of Page
Fullwidth = Browser("Wikipedia, the free encycloped").Object.document.body.scrollwidth
```

Once we  found the complete page size, we need to find the client size (how much browser can show)

```
#Get the visible height - Viewable part of the page
BrowserHeight = Browser("Wikipedia, the free encycloped").Object.document.body.clientHeight

#Get the visible width - Viewable part of the page
Browserwidth = Browser("Wikipedia, the free encycloped").Object.document.body.clientwidth
```

Next we need to import required dot net libraries using Dot Net Factory

```
Set oGraphics=DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Drawing.Graphics")

Set oPoint=DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Drawing.Point")

Set oImgFormat=DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat","System.Drawing", Nothing)

Set oImageLib = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Drawing.Image")

Set oPens=DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Drawing.Pens","System.Drawing")
```

As a final step, we need to loop through the page and take screenprints separately. finally using Dotnet library we will merge the images using graphics. draw method. It is easy to implement, complete set of code is available in the above mentioned link for reference

Answer (score -1):

If you would like a single screenshot of the whole page, try using [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp).

There's a handy PDF with more info on how to go about it (http://download.techsmith.com/snagit/docs/comserver/enu/snagitcom.pdf)

In QTP it might look like this:

```
Sub Capture_Scroll_Image ()

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oSnag = CreateObject("SNAGIT.ImageCapture")

oSnag.IncludeCursor = False
oSnag.OutputImageFile.FileType = 5
oSnag.OutputImageFile.FileNamingMethod = 1
oSnag.OutputImageFile.Directory = "C:\Screens\"
oSnag.OutputImageFile.Filename = "Name"
oSnag.EnablePreviewWindow = False
oSnag.AutoScrollOptions.AutoScrollMethod= 1
oSnag.Capture() 

Wait (1)
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
capDone = oSnag.IsCaptureDone

Do Until oSnag.IsCaptureDone
Loop 
Set oSnag=Nothing
Set objShell=NothingEnd Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer does not refer to the question but to a question asked in an answer to the main question. Doh!